# Live streaming from Android app to Facebook

Tags: android, facebook

Is it possible to stream video from Android app to Face book live?

I would like to publish a live video from my application to face book using my device camera.Is that possible? If it is possible, where should I start with?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible, I haven't tried this before but there is a [Facebook Live Api](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/videos/live-video/) available you can check with that for more detail.